# how to authenticate RESTful API in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, rest, laravel, restful-authentication, laravel-5

How to authenticate RESTful API in Laravel 5?
I am using Laravel 5 to build a RESTful API & I want to use those API for mobile application.

I have also seen http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication
but not getting any related example so,please provide me sample example or appropriate link for authenticate RESTful API in Laravel 5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was looking for the same answer and I found this link very useful with detailed information and usage for L5 with the use of [JWT](http://jwt.io/) .

[JSON Web Token](http://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs)

Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Is it possible to add a sort of 'remember me' function for JWT?

Comment: Great article from Toptal - thanks for sharing the link. I also found https://jwt.io/introduction/ was a good introduction to JWT (contains no Laravel-specific info).

Comment: Now there is laravel 5.4 version available, so is there is another convenient way to make API ?

Answer (score 5):

The Concept to use here would be Middleware:
To get you started, put this in your API-Controller's ctors:

```
public function __construct()
{
    // reqires Authentificataion before access
    $this->middleware('auth.basic');
}
```

Your app should then be able to call the resources like

```
http://user:pass@yourapp.com/yourresource/1
```

Comment: I want to authenticate my API only once or using authentication token

Comment: in this case, you would have to write your own middleware. Laravel only provies a hand full of middlewares out of the box. see https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Kernel.php Writing your own isn't that hard, see https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style or the laravel docs

Comment: since i am using this construct, i dont have one right now. it also depends on your 'authentication token'.